# How to decompose multi-assignment same line in Java?

Tags: java

I've been searching in web but I did not find anything.
How should I read this?

```
e = d = b - a
```

Should I read it from right-to-left or left-to-right?
I think it should be right-to-left?

The equivalent code is

```
d=b-a
e=d

??
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, `=` associates right-to-left in Java.

Comment: _"All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; **assignment operators are evaluated right to left.**"_ - [Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) (emphasis by me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I think it should be right-to-left?* -> Yes.

### Java Language Specification

If you want to know more; read the Java Language Specification on expressions. The Java Language specification is a great document to learn more about how Java *exactly* works!

For example:

### Chapter 15 - Expressions

> Much of the work in a program is done by evaluating expressions,
>   either for their side effects, such as assignments to variables, or
>   for their values, which can be used as arguments or operands in larger
>   expressions, or to affect the execution sequence in statements, or
>   both.
>
> This chapter specifies the meanings of expressions and the rules for
>   their evaluation.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html

### Evaluation order

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7 .

### Assignment

(not as simple as you might think)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26

Specifically:

### 15.26. Assignment Operators

> There are 12 assignment operators; all are syntactically
>   right-associative (they group **right-to-left**). Thus, `a=b=c` means
>   `a=(b=c)`, which assigns the value of `c` to `b` and then assigns the value
>   of `b` to `a`.